# Transition multiple elements at the same time on Vue component render

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js, vue-transitions

Simple case shown in the following jsfiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/hsak2rdu/

I want to swap and animate two elements, but fail.  As you can see after clicking the toggle button in the playground, the second element flashes into the final position.

I want them both animated at the same time, like crossing each other. Is it possible?

**Template:**

```
<div id="app">
  <div class="dom" v-for="(_d, _i) in list" :key="_d.id" :style="{ top: _i * 50 + 'px'}">
    <span>{{_d.text}}{{_i}}</span>
  </div>
  <button @click="handle">Toggle</button>
  {{list}}
</div>
```

**JS:**

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    show: true,
    list: [
      {
        id:1,
        text:'First'
      },
      {
        id:2,
        text:'Second'
      }
    ]
  },
  methods:{
    handle: function (){
      console.log("DEBUG", this.list)
      let a = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.list[0]));
      let b = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.list[1]))
      this.$set(this.list, 0, b);
      this.$set(this.list, 1, a);
    }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only necessary change is to wrap the `v-for` in a `<transition-group>`:

```html
<transition-group tag="div" name="list">
  <div class="dom" v-for="(_d, _i) in list" :key="_d.id" :style="{ top: _i * 20 + 'px' }">
    <span>{{_d.text}}{{_i}}</span>
  </div>
</transition-group>
```

From the [docs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/transitions.html#List-Move-Transitions):

> This might seem like magic, but under the hood, Vue is using an animation technique called [FLIP](https://aerotwist.com/blog/flip-your-animations/) to smoothly transition elements from their old position to their new position using transforms

Here's a demo:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: () => ({
    show: true,
    list: [
      {
        id:1,
        text:'First'
      },
      {
        id:2,
        text:'Second'
      }
    ]
  }),
  methods:{
    handle: function (){
      console.log("DEBUG", this.list)
      let a = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.list[0]));
      let b = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.list[1]))
      this.$set(this.list, 0, b);
      this.$set(this.list, 1, a);
    }
  }
});
```

```css
.dom{
  position: absolute;
  transition: all 1s linear;
  opacity: 1;
}
button{
  margin-top: 50px;
}
#app{
  margin-top: 50px;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div id="app">
  <transition-group tag="div" name="list">
    <div class="dom" v-for="(_d, _i) in list" :key="_d.id" :style="{ top: _i * 20 + 'px' }">
      <span>{{_d.text}}{{_i}}</span>
    </div>
  </transition-group>
  <button @click="handle">Toggle</button>
  {{list}}
</div>

<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
```